# friend member function in C++ - forward declaration not working

Tags: c++, friend, circular-dependency, friend-function

I'm having a situation similar to the one described in [Specify a class member function as a friend of another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546391/specify-a-class-member-function-as-a-friend-of-another-class).

However in my case, class B needs to know class A since it's using it, so the solution given in that thread is not working  for me. I tried to give also a forward declaration to the function itself but it didn't work as well. It seems that each class need the full definition of the other...

Is there any easy way to solve it? I prefer a solution which doesn't involve new classes which wrap one of the old classes.

code example:

```
//A.h
class B; //not helping
void B::fB(); //not helping

class A
{
public:
    friend void B::fB();
    void fA(){};
protected:
    void fA_protected(){};
};

//B.h
#include "A.h"

class B
{
private:
    A a;

public:
    void fB(){ a.fA_protected();} // this function should call the protected function
    void fB2(){ a.fA(); } 
};
```

Thanks for the helpers!

(By the way this my first question, I hope I explain myself clearly)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you illustrated this with a code sample.

Comment: Friend Member Functions is against the paradigm of encapsulation. If you give your exact problem, i am sure, there will be a better solution for that than friend members.

Comment: Hey juanchopanza, sorry - I added now a code exapmle! user1767754 - I need to use some inner functionality of A and I want to make sure that no other functions in B will use fA_protected accidentally.

Comment: I've only come across one case where we had to use a friend in 10 yrs of programming and I'm pretty sure the reason was because it was too much work to write something correctly

Comment: Do you may change `A a` to `std::unique_ptr<A> a` ? That would break the circular dependency and solve your problem.

Comment: I'm looking for something very portable, I don't think unique_ptr is suitable for me.

Comment: @user3322745: If you can't use `std::unique_ptr` (C++11), you may use (deprecated) `std::auto_ptr` or raw pointer.

Comment: Can't use auto_ptr either. How a raw pointer would help?

Comment: if `B` uses `A* a` instead of `A a`, you may forward declare `A` instead of `#include "A.h"`, So `class A` may be declared after `B` and friend member would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change B to take a pointer on A, following may help:
(I use raw pointer as you can't use smart pointer according to comment).

```
//A.h
#include "B.h"

class A
{
public:
    friend void B::fB();
    void fA() {};
protected:
    void fA_protected(){};
};

//B.h
class A; // forward declaration

class B
{
private:
    A* a;

public:
    B();
    ~B();                       // rule of 3
    B(const B& b);              // rule of 3
    B& operator = (const B&);   // rule of 3

    void fB(); // this function should call the protected function
    void fB2(); 
};

//B.cpp

#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

B::B() : a(new A) {}
B::~B() { delete a; }                      // rule of 3
B::B(const B& b) : a(new A(*b.a)) {}       // rule of 3
B& B::operator = (const B&) { *a = *b.a; return *this; } // rule of 3

void B::fB() { a->fA_protected();}
void B::fB2() { a->fA(); }
```