# Friend function - member is inaccessible

Tags: c++, friend-function

I'm taking a C++ course, and I came across something I can't wrap my head around. I've tried searching for an answer, but I've come up short.

```
class A {
    friend void C::dec(A&);
private:
    int field;
};

class C {
public:
    void dec(A& a);
};

void C::dec(A& a) { a.field--; } <-- member A::field is inaccessible
```

I am aware that for this to work, class A should be declared before, but defined after, class C. But I'm struggling to understand why.

So why is the class member A::field inaccessible when class A is defined before class C?

Comment: Compiling your code gives me `prog.cc:2:17: fatal error: use of undeclared identifier 'C'` on the second line, as expected. Which compiler are you using? It seems to be ignoring the error silently...

Comment: @Quentin You need to forward declare class C

Comment: @John declaring `class C;` before `A` yields `prog.cc:4:17: fatal error: incomplete type 'C' named in nested name specifier`. [Wandbox link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gNTDeQyNCqTHFjpj)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify a class member function as a friend of another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546391/specify-a-class-member-function-as-a-friend-of-another-class)

Comment: @John befriending only the member function is possible, as mentioned in the question. I still cannot reproduce the question's behaviour that the friend declaration compile, but has no effect.

Comment: The compiler is probably giving you an error saying that `C` is undeclared *as well as* an error that the member is inaccessible. See https://godbolt.org/z/fY6eCV. You should not try to reason about later errors, they often make no sense since the compiler must make additional assumptions to continue compilation even though there are previous errors. If you did not get such a previous error, please tell us what compiler you used and check that you tried to compile *exactly* that code.

Comment: @TruthSeeker It does, thank you. I've been looking for post like that, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the friend declaration, it's just `C` is unknown where you declare it in `A`.

So you define `C` and forward declare `A`, then just define `C` as you already did.

```
class A;

class C {
public:
    void dec(A& a);
};

class A {
    friend void C::dec(A&);
private:
    int field;
};


void C::dec(A& a) { a.field--; }
```

Comment: OP is aware of this solution, they're asking *why* their original code fails.

Comment: @Quentin _it's just C is unknown where you declare it in A_